# PHP Mail() function not working in cpanel hosting

Tags: php, cpanel

The PHP `mail()` function is not working from my cpanel.

My cpanel ports are all open and by default the email ID is also set in cpanel.

MY code

```
$to = "rahul@gmail.com";
$subject = "My subject"; 
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@host4future.in" ;
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

Comment: Show me your code.

Comment: MY code `code`
`$to = "rahul@gmail.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@host4future.in" ;
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct, but most hosts block the mail function by default and/or prevent the user nobody from sending emails.

In [Tweak Settings on WHM](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/server-configuration/tweak-settings/), try turning off the option "Prevent 'nobody' from sending mail".

In [the PHP Configuration Editor (in advanced mode)](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/security/how-to-edit-your-php-ini-file/) check if the mail function is listed in the [disable_functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive.

If none of that work, check if [the Exim](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/service-configuration/exim-configuration-manager/) is up and running and if the [sendmail_path in php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an apache misconfiguration. I saw in logs only this `unable to set gid=993 or uid=0 (euid=0): forcing real = effective`
And the fix was to add `LimitUIDRange 0 2000` to apache mpm_prefork.conf file and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );

$from = "adfghh@gmail.com";
$to = "lthser@gmail.com";

$subject = "PHP Mail Sending Checking";
$message = "PHP Mail Works Fine";
$headers = "From: " . $from;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.